# How do I add a dash after the fifth term in a string of numbers?

Tags: regex, for-loop, if-statement, stringr

I am trying to do some data tidying in R with zip codes and some are 5 digits and others are 9 that I want to change from XXXXXXXXX to XXXXX-XXXX. df is the dataframe containing these zip codes with multiple repetitions of the same zip code.

```
a <- df$Zip_Code

for (i in a){
   if (length(i) > 5){
   str_replace(i, '(\d{5})','\1-')
}}
```

The code runs find but the value 'a' doesn't change so I am wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in base R or `stringr` using the below approaches. You do not need a `for` loop or `if` statement since R uses vectorization:

Data

```
zip <- c(12345, 12345, 123456789, 123456789)
```

#### `substr`

Use `substr` to split the first 5 digits from the last 4 then `paste0` to put it all back together

```
zip[nchar(zip) > 5] <- paste0(substr(zip[nchar(zip) > 5], 1, 5),
                              "-",
                              substr(zip[nchar(zip) > 5], 5, 9))

# [1] "12345"       "12345"       "12345-56789" "12345-56789"
```

#### `gsub`

You could alternatively use `gsub` to make it more elegant:

```
zip[nchar(zip) > 5] <- gsub('^(.{5})(.*)$', 
                            '\\1-\\2', 
                            zip[nchar(zip) > 5])

# [1] "12345"      "12345"      "12345-6789" "12345-6789"
```

#### `stringr`

since you tagged `stringr`, here is an approach using `stringr::str_replace`:

```
zip[nchar(zip) > 5] <- stringr::str_replace(zip[nchar(zip) > 5], 
                     pattern = "(.{5})(.*)", 
                     replacement = "\\1-\\2")

# [1] "12345"      "12345"      "12345-6789" "12345-6789"
```